# Mojolicious: Inconsistent URL Decoding of Route Placeholders

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I want to access a resource in a Restful API where the resource identifier contains special characters.  I'm therefore url_encoding the identifier, but I'm getting inconsistent automatic decoding behavior in Mojolicious for the placeholders.

The following is a test script that tests a simple resource identifier, one that contains a space, one with a plus, and one with a slash.  I'm url_encoding each of these before sending my request, but the 2nd two fail for different reasons.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Data::Dump qw(pp);
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Test::Exception;
use Test::More;
use URL::Encode qw(url_encode url_decode);
use WWW::Mechanize;

# Case 1: Access a resource using Standard Placeholders
get '/my/app/standard_placeholder/:id' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $id_raw     = $c->stash('id');
    my $id_decoded = url_decode($id_raw);

    $c->render( json => { raw => $id_raw, decoded => $id_decoded } );
};

# Shut the server down.
get '/my/api/shutdown' => sub {
    exit 0;
};

# Fork for Client and Server
if ( my $pid = fork ) {
    note "Waiting for the server to start";
    sleep 2;

    run_test();

    # Clean up server process and we’re done
    waitpid( $pid, 0 );

} else {
    local @ARGV = qw(daemon);

    app->log( Mojo::Log->new( path => "$0.log", level => 'debug' ) );
    app->start;
}

exit 0;

### Client

sub run_test {
    plan tests => 2;

    my $ua         = Mojo::UserAgent->new();
    my $server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';

    # Standard Placeholders:  ([^/.]+)
    # Relaxed Placeholders:   ([^/]+)
    # Wildcard Placeholders:  (.+)

    subtest 'Standard Placeholders testing url_encoding of route identifiers' => sub {
        my @ids = (
            "foobar",    #
            "a space",
            "a+plus",
            "a/slash",
        );

        plan tests => 3 * @ids;

        for my $id (@ids) {
            my $id_encoded = url_encode($id);
            my $tx         = $ua->get("$server_url/my/app/standard_placeholder/$id_encoded");

        SKIP: {
                is( $tx->res->code, 200, "Fetch Resource at " . pp($id) )
                    or skip "Error in response", 2;

                is( $tx->res->json->{raw},     $id_encoded, "json->{raw} eq " . pp($id_encoded) );
                is( $tx->res->json->{decoded}, $id,         "json->{decoded} eq " . pp($id) );
            }
        }
    };

    subtest 'Shutdown the server' => sub {
        plan tests => 2;

        dies_ok {
            my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( timeout => 3 );
            $mech->get("$server_url/my/api/shutdown");
        }
        'shutdown occurred';

        like $@, qr{Error GETing .*?shutdown: Server closed connection without sending any data back},
            'detected closed connection';
    };
}

1;
```

And the output:

```
mhall@dev19:~$ ./mojo_placeholders.pl
# Waiting for the server to start
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
1..2
# Subtest: Standard Placeholders testing url_encoding of route identifiers
    1..12
    ok 1 - Fetch Resource at "foobar"
    ok 2 - json->{raw} eq "foobar"
    ok 3 - json->{decoded} eq "foobar"
    ok 4 - Fetch Resource at "a space"
    ok 5 - json->{raw} eq "a+space"
    ok 6 - json->{decoded} eq "a space"
    ok 7 - Fetch Resource at "a+plus"
    not ok 8 - json->{raw} eq "a%2Bplus"
    #   Failed test 'json->{raw} eq "a%2Bplus"'
    #   at ./mojo_placeholders.pl line 89.
    #          got: 'a+plus'
    #     expected: 'a%2Bplus'
    not ok 9 - json->{decoded} eq "a+plus"
    #   Failed test 'json->{decoded} eq "a+plus"'
    #   at ./mojo_placeholders.pl line 90.
    #          got: 'a plus'
    #     expected: 'a+plus'
    not ok 10 - Fetch Resource at "a/slash"
    #   Failed test 'Fetch Resource at "a/slash"'
    #   at ./mojo_placeholders.pl line 85.
    #          got: '404'
    #     expected: '200'
    ok 11 # skip Error in response
    ok 12 # skip Error in response
    # Looks like you failed 3 tests of 12.
not ok 1 - Standard Placeholders testing url_encoding of route identifiers
#   Failed test 'Standard Placeholders testing url_encoding of route identifiers'
#   at ./mojo_placeholders.pl line 93.
# Subtest: Shutdown the server
    1..2
    ok 1 - shutdown occurred
    ok 2 - detected closed connection
ok 2 - Shutdown the server
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I confirm the behaviour makes no sense. Only unencoded slashes should have meaning, and there seems to be a problem re-encoding `+`. (It probably re-encodes to normalize the encoding to compare against the path. I haven no idea why it places encoded values in the stash, though, but that's not the issue here.)

Answer (score 2):

So there are several things going on here. First generally `/` vs `%2F` is a very fraught thing. You can read an interesting thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-web-sig/IAPhwezOJ7I and notice that Mojolicious itself was issued a CVE over the potential for path traversal https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2011-1589/. That said if you use wildcard placeholders you can still recover `/` in your placeholders. Finally your test is (while I'm sure functional) not using the Mojolicious test facilities which would avoid much of your architecture, leaving room for more tests. Here was my quick cleanup.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojo::Base -strict;

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::Util qw(url_escape url_unescape);

use Test::More;
use Test::Mojo;

my $cb = sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $id_raw     = $c->stash('id');
    my $id_decoded = url_unescape $id_raw;

    $c->render( json => { raw => $id_raw, decoded => $id_decoded } );
};
get '/standard/:id' => $cb;
get '/relaxed/#id'  => $cb;
get '/wildcard/*id' => $cb;


# Standard Placeholders:  ([^/.]+)
# Relaxed Placeholders:   ([^/]+)
# Wildcard Placeholders:  (.+)

my $t = Test::Mojo->new;

my @ids = (
    "foobar",
    "a space",
    "a+plus",
    "a/slash",
);

plan tests => 3;

for my $type (qw/standard relaxed wildcard/) {
  subtest "Type $type" => sub {
    plan tests => 4 * @ids;

    for my $id (@ids) {
      my $id_encoded = url_escape $id;
      $t->get_ok("/$type/$id_encoded")
        ->status_is(200)
        ->json_is('/raw',     $id_encoded, "$type raw test for $id_encoded")
        ->json_is('/decoded', $id,         "$type decoded test for $id");
    }
  };
}
```

I didn't correct your tests, just ported them as written (and extended for all three placeholder types).

Comment: Thanks! This solved a related problem for me: `https://10.0.0.54/map/51.5526/0.018` etc. etc. which needs *relaxed* placeholders. I hadn't used them before.